# Fatal Error: Bad Boolean on Git Push Attempt

Tags: git, github, terminal

I get this error "fatal: bad boolean config value 'origin' for 'push.autosetupremote" and now I can't push my code anymore

This error came after I tried to make it so that when I can push code from other branches with just the 'git push' command. Now I can't fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a bad configuration, you can run the following command to unset that config value: `git config --unset push.autosetupremote`.

Also, if you want to just type `git push` and only push the current branch that you are on, you would need to set `git config --set push.default upstream`

HTH